# Calculate space complexity of list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have written the below code:

```
nums = [0,2,1,5,3,4]
```

Here, `nums` is an array of distinct integers from `0 to nums.length - 1`

```
def new_array(nums):
  return [nums[num] for num in nums]
```

Please help me understand if the space complexity of above code is `O(n)` or `O(1).`

My understanding is that the space complexity is `O(n)` because a new list is created via `list comprehension.`

How the above code can be rewritten with space complexity `O(1)?`

Comment: I personally think it should be `O(n)` also, but I could be wrong. Since list comprehension is just a fancy way of writing a for loop and appending to a list (but with some optimizations of course). Even with the optimizations, you're still looping over N times (length of nums) to create the list, so I think it should be O(n) rather than O(1), which I believe is the same as the time complexity here.

Comment: It couldn't possibly be O(1), could it? You are creating a *new list* that is going to have the same length as the input, no? So it must be O(N).

Comment: @rv.kvetch yes, a list comprehension isn't even all that optimized, the main thing is you just avoid doing the method resolution of `result_list.append` in the loop, but you can almost get there by using `result_append = result_list.append` and using `result_append(x)` in the loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually it's not the "new list" that takes linear space but the "input" does. All they have is that "input" and a function they never call (and defining the function takes only O(1) space).

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm presuming they mean to call the function, of course. Normally, when you talk about algorithmic complexity, you will often just be looking at the function under the assumption that it is being called with appropriate inputs.

Comment: @KellyBundy also, I was under the impression that space complexity usually doesn't consider the size of the inputs itself, but it has been ages since I've seen a formal treatment of this stuff

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Bah, they edited, splitting the code. What I commented on was a code block creating a list and defining a function, followed by asking about the complexity of that...

Comment: You can rewrite as a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) as long as you don't actually need a `list`, just a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

### You're creating a new list, so the space complexity is `O(n)`.

A list comprehension returns a new list, and the list you construct contains the same number of elements as the original list. The memory used to store the elements of the list you pass in and the memory used to store the elements of the returned list are separate.

Comment: How the above code can be rewritten with space complexity `O(1)?`

Comment: @meallhour what is you actual problem here? Are you trying to solve sometime? Or are you just trying to understand space complexity?

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I am trying to solve above code in `O(1)` space complexity.

Comment: @mealhour Modify `nums` in-place. Keep in mind that your program won't use `O(n)` space overall, since it needs to store at least one list, but the function itself will only use `O(1)` additional space, which is the best you can possibly do.

Answer (score 0):

According to python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension) list comprehension is a syntax sugar for a standard for so your code is equivalent to the following

```
nums = [0,2,1,5,3,4]

def new_array(nums):
  L = []
  for num in nums:
    L.append(nums[num])
  return L
```

Which is `O(n)`

Comment: How the above code can be rewritten with space complexity `O(1)?`

Comment: @meallhour it cannot, because you are creating a new list, it doesn't matter how you create a new list, it is always going to require auxiliary space, how could it not? Now, you could also *not* create a new list, and you could mutate the original list-inplace to get this result without auxiliary space